# how to play song in raw folder continously, and no looping

Tags: android, arrays, audio, media-player

im newbie here, can you help me?? i want to play all song in my raw folder sequentially, after all song finished playing i want no looping.

i have tried this code but it keeps looping after allsong playing
 {

```
int [] sound;
int soundke = 0;
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_kubus);

    sound = new int[] {R.raw.swoosh2, R.raw.swoosh1, R.raw.swoosh2};

    mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(kubus.this, sound[0]);

    mediaPlayer.start();

    mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
            play();

        }
    });

}

private void play () {
    soundke = (soundke + 1) % 3;
    AssetFileDescriptor afd = this.getResources().openRawResourceFd(sound[soundke]);

    try {
        mediaPlayer.reset();
        mediaPlayer.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(), afd.getStartOffset(), afd.getDeclaredLength());
        mediaPlayer.prepare();
        mediaPlayer.start();
        afd.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {

    }
}
```

it still keeps looping after all song playing. i want not looping after all song playing, thanks for your helping

Comment: looping mean start from first track or loop on last track ?

Comment: on last track..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  int [] sound;
    int soundke = 0;
    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_kubus);

        sound = new int[] {R.raw.swoosh2, R.raw.swoosh1, R.raw.swoosh2};

        mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(kubus.this, sound[0]);
        mediaPlayer.setLooping(false);
        mediaPlayer.start();

        mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                if(soundke < sound.length-1){
                   play(++soundke);
                }else{
                    soundke=0; 
                    mediaPlayer.stop();    
}
            }
        });

    }

    private void play (int track) {
        //soundke = (soundke + 1) % 3;
        AssetFileDescriptor afd = this.getResources().openRawResourceFd(sound[track]);

        try {
            mediaPlayer.reset();
            mediaPlayer.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(), afd.getStartOffset(), afd.getDeclaredLength());
            mediaPlayer.setLooping(false);
            mediaPlayer.prepare();
            mediaPlayer.start();
            afd.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {

        }
    }
```

Comment: @Ewa Saputra let me edit my answer real quick then try it

Comment: @Ewa Saputra  now try it

Comment: eror when the last song has finished playing the application closes itself

Comment: what its says in log cat . which line is the error ?

Comment: i dont know which line is error but error like this 
   FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.smkm2p.apkfortunanetra, PID: 27163
    java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=3; index=3

Comment: `if(soundke < sound.length-1)` just add `-1` after `sound.length`